# CSS Selectors (or statement, containers, separator, etc)

Tags: css, css-selectors, containers, separator

Are there containers for CSS Selectors?

I'm simply curious if there's a more elegant way to do this without repeating the class:

```
#div1 .divClass, #div2 .divClass { color:cyan; }
```

This is what I had in mind, but I don't think there's a way to do it.

```
#div1,#div2 > .divClass { }
[#div1,#div2] .divClass { }
```

Comment: Not available currently, but it is being played with in Gecko and WebKit as `:-moz-any()` and `-webkit-any()` respectively. It is being proposed as `:matches()` in the CSS4 Selectors spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

It seems a case where you can add a class for both divs.

```
<div id="div1" class="sharedClass"></div>
<div id="div2" class="sharedClass"></div>

.sharedClass > .divClass { color: cyan; }
```

Anyway, this question can have multiple answers. Consider looking at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which extends CSS capabilities. Then you could do something awesome like this:

```
.divClass {
    /* ... */
}

#div1 {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    .divClass;
}

#div2 {
    color: cyan;
    border: 1px solid green;
    .divClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules), which is a stylesheet language which can be compiled into ordinary CSS. It might not do exactly what you're after in your specific case (but then again, it might, I haven't tried) but it sounds like it would be useful to you.

Comment: I was just thinking the same as @Karl-Nicoll, haven't dabbled with it myself but heard its really useful for reducing the size of your css file.

Comment: LESS does look pretty sweet! I'll have to check that out, thanks. I'm going to wait a while before selecting an accepted answer.

Comment: Or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) which has [@extend](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) (last time I checked at least, LESS didn't have this ability).